# Create RegEx control for URL

Tags: javascript, c#, regex, asp.net-mvc, vue.js

I have a problem with my current web application. Indeed, when I put the current link : https://localhost:44311/#shop, my page displayed perfectly. Here a picture :
[image]

But then when I try to change my URL to : https://localhost:44311/#/ , to verify the control of the redirection, the content displayed into the same content, here a picture of what happened :
[image]

Currently, all my ajax calls are called again and again and again (an infinite loop).

I'm trying to add control regex for #/, and try to respect #/xxxx/xxxxx. But without success. If you can help me, it could be very nice !
Here my JS where I manage the loadpages :

```
var ui = {
   controller: {
       page: {}
   },
   component: {
       category: null
   }
};
ui.controller.pageLoad = function (hash = null) {
   if (hash === null) {
       hash = window.location.hash;
       if (hash.length < 2 || hash[0] !== "#") {
           hash = "/shop";
       }
   } else if (hash.length < 2 || hash[0] === "#" && hash[1] === '/') { // add control regex for #/, must respect #/xxxx/xxxxx
       hash = "/shop";
   }

   $.get(hash.substring(1), function (data) {
       ui.controller.page = null;
       $("#content").html(data);
   }).fail(function (error) {
       $.get("/Home/Error?status=" + error.status, function (data) {
           ui.controller.page = null;
           $("#content").html(data);
       });
   });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a `isValidHash` function, and use it in your `if` statement:

```js
function isValidHash(hash) {
  return typeof hash === "string" && /^#(\/[a-z0-9-]+)+$/.test(hash);
}

function test(v) {
  console.log(`'${v}' is ${isValidHash(v) ? '' : 'NOT '}valid`);
}

test(null);            // NO - not a string
test('#');             // NO - too short
test('#shop');         // NO - no slash
test('#/shop');        // YES
test('#/shop/item-9'); // YES
```

Comment: Oh yes thank you it works. Have you some link to share with me Sir about the regEx ? I'm still a beginner ahah. Thanks again!

Comment: Sure, you can [go here](https://regex101.com/r/yqqlyv/1), see that regex in action, and on the right you'll find the explanation of everything in this regex